# Group by multiple columns, but returning only one line. Agreggating on only one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

If I have this table

```
Contract : Code : Date
62          11    01/01/2016
62          16    01/02/2016
62          09    01/03/2016
```

And I want to return only this line,

```
Contract : Code : Date
62          09    01/03/2016
```

I want to do a select contract, max(data), code **group by contract**

But I can't since the code column should be aggregated in some form.

I have tried every aggregate function, but in a larger data set none of them work. like, max, min, sum, count etc.
I need only the code for that contract and date.

Can you guys help me? Thanks so much

Comment: I think ANSI answer would be to use a subquery, joining the same table by `contract` and selecting `code`

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has a very convenient extension called `distinct on`, which does this quite efficiently:

```
select distinct on (contract) t.*
from t
order by contract, date desc;
```

`distinct on` returns one row for each value of the keys in parentheses.  The row is the first row encountered -- based on the `order by` -- for each set of values.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple general pattern that does this using aggregation:

Find the max, then join back to the table.

I assume the table is R(Contract, Code, Date).

Note how I rename the attribute in M to match the name of the attribute in R.

```
WITH M as (
    select contract, max(date) as date 
    from R group by contract)
  select * from R natural join M;
```

Window functions would do the same too.

If you want only the very max, then:

```
WITH M as (
    select max(date) as date 
    from R)
  select * from R natural join M;
```